# NotePad++ regex find between

Tags: regex, notepad++

I wan't to pull out all instances of "brand":"SOMETHING HERE" in my document where SOMETHING HERE could be any number of things but its always in the format of the above... how do I do this with NP++

Answer (score 4):

This regex should do it...

```
"brand":"(.*?)"
```

Comment: maybe it helps to know that there's tons of text and 'other crap' that surround the "brand":"SOMETHING HERE" text. So I'm really looking to extract just the "brand":"SOMETHING HERE" text

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + F, check 'Regular expression', select 'Replace' tab. In 'find what', type

```
"brand":"[\S]+"
```

Leave 'Replace with' empty to remove all instances of "brand":"[one or more non white-space characters]"

Comment: maybe it helps to know that there's tons of text and 'other crap' that surround the "brand":"SOMETHING HERE" text. So I'm really looking to extract just the "brand":"SOMETHING HERE" text

Comment: It seems Notepad++ does not have a comprehensive regex implementation. Do you have any other tools available (i.e. a scripting language)?

Answer (score -1):

```
   (brand:).*$
```

should work in NP++

Comment: too greedy and ignores quotes. it will only get one match from **"brand":"foo" "brand":"bar"** and it will be **foo" "brand":"bar**

Comment: maybe it helps to know that there's tons of text and 'other crap' that surround the "brand":"SOMETHING HERE" text. So I'm really looking to extract just the "brand":"SOMETHING HERE" text